# Json writing issue with values update

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, 
The intention of this code is to create a json with informations provided by the user, but in the innermost loop the values are always being updated to the last values inserted by the user.

```
import json


while True:
    keepGoing = True
    pay_obj = {
        'id': {0: {
        }
        }
    }
    pay_res = {
        "res": {
        }

    }
    pay_access = {
        'type': 'type',
        'acl': 'acl',
        'value': ''
    }
    obj_id = str(input('Insert obj ID: '))
    pay_obj[obj_id] = pay_obj['id']
    while keepGoing == True:
        print(pay_res)
        res_id = str(input('Insert resource ID: '))
        pay_res[res_id] = pay_res['res']
        type = str(input(f'Insert the data type for {res_id}: '))
        pay_access['type'] = type.upper()
        acl = str(input(f'Insert the access control level for {res_id}: '))
        pay_access['acl'] = acl.upper()
        pay_res[res_id] = pay_access
        cont = input('More resources?(y/n): ')
        if cont == 'n':
            pay_obj[obj_id]=pay_res
            del pay_obj['id']
            del pay_obj[obj_id]['res']
            pay_obj = json.dumps(pay_obj,indent=4)
            print(pay_obj)
            del pay_obj
            break
```

The expected output should be a json like that

```
{
    "3303": {
        "3303": {
            "type": "STRING",
            "acl": "R",
            "value": ""
        },
        "3304": {
            "type": "STRING",
            "acl": "W",
            "value": ""
        }
    }
}
```

But with the right values, not the last values inside the resources.

Comment: So what's wrong with the output you currently get?

Comment: The innermost area, where you can find the {"type":"type","acl":"acl","value":"value"}, is always receiving the last introduced values, instead of each value already introduced before.

Comment: Well, you never create a new data structure but keep on re-using the same ``pay_access`` again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to ncica code, I just implemented an extra loop to introduce even more object on the same json:

```
import json

main={}

j=True
while j:
    obj_id = str(input('Insert obj ID: '))
    obj_temp={}
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing == True:
        res_id = raw_input('Insert resource ID for object ID %s: ' % obj_id)
        type = raw_input('Insert the data type for resource ID %s: '% res_id)
        val = raw_input('Insert the value for resource ID %s: ' % res_id)
        acl = raw_input('Insert the access control level for resource ID %s: ' % res_id)
        tmp_res = {"type": type, "acl": acl.upper(), "value": val.upper()}
        obj_temp[res_id]=tmp_res
        cont = raw_input('More resources?(y/n): ')
        if cont=='n':
            keepGoing=False
            cont1 = raw_input('More obj?(y/n): ')
            main[obj_id]=obj_temp
            if cont1=='n':
                j=False
print main
```

example:

```
Insert obj ID: 1
Insert resource ID for object ID 1: 10
Insert the data type for resource ID 10: type10
Insert the value for resource ID 10: value10
Insert the access control level for resource ID 10: access10
More resources?(y/n): y
Insert resource ID for object ID 1: 20
Insert the data type for resource ID 20: type20
Insert the value for resource ID 20: value20
Insert the access control level for resource ID 20: access20
More resources?(y/n): n
More obj?(y/n): y
Insert obj ID: 2
Insert resource ID for object ID 2: 30
Insert the data type for resource ID 30: type30
Insert the value for resource ID 30: value30
Insert the access control level for resource ID 30: access30
More resources?(y/n): n
More obj?(y/n): n

{  
  '1':{  
    '10':{  
      'type':'type10',
      'value':'VALUE10',
      'acl':'ACCESS10'
    },
    '20':{  
      'type':'type20',
      'value':'VALUE20',
      'acl':'ACCESS20'
    }
  },
  '2':{  
    '30':{  
      'type':'type30',
      'value':'VALUE30',
      'acl':'ACCESS30'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should looks something like:

```
d = {}
res_id = str(input('Insert resource ID: '))
res_id_ = res_id
while True:
    type = str(input(f'Insert the data type for {res_id}: '))
    acl = str(input(f'Insert the access control level for {res_id}: '))
    pay_access ={res_id:{
        'type': type,
        'acl': acl,
        'value': ''
    }}
    d.update(pay_access)
    res_id = int(res_id) + 1
    cont = input('More resources?(y/n): ')
    if cont == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break

data = {res_id_:d}
print (json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

output:

```
Insert resource ID: 3303
Insert the data type for 3303: STRING
Insert the access control level for 3303: R
More resources?(y/n): y
Insert the data type for 3304: STRING
Insert the access control level for 3304: W
More resources?(y/n): n
{
    "3303": {
        "3303": {
            "type": "STRING",
            "acl": "R",
            "value": ""
        },
        "3304": {
            "type": "STRING",
            "acl": "W",
            "value": ""
        }
    }
}
```